# Can 2019 CC ai files be placed into 2019 cc ai file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I used to be able to place 2017 ai file into another ai file but not with new 2019 CC version, is it still possible?

Comment: Yes its possible

Comment: Have you tried? I feel like this is easily answerable by doing a simple test. Check [ask] to learn more about good questions, and take the [tour] to learn more about the site in general.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What happens when you try?  Is there some error message?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Linking AI to AI is a major feature and don't see why they would remove that.